# Elastic search over an already existing lucene index

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have a system that uses lucene. Now for a few reasons I would like to add a distributed search feature over it.

The question is can I use the existing lucene index created by the IndexWriter of lucene, for searching with elastic search or should I create a new index using ES's IndexWriter.

P.S I discovered over the web that this is possible with solr, but afaik couldn't find anything tangible for es. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reindex into ElasticSearch, you can't reuse an existing Lucene index.

Comment: Thank you @DrTech. Over to solr now :)

Comment: @Ramprakash I wouldn't abandon ES just because you can't use your existing Lucene index - ES is a lot more than just distributed Lucene

Comment: Yeah I understand! But in my use case I find solr satisfactory and yeah re-indexing is way costly in my case!

Comment: FYI, I am using ES for a new application I am writing. The current one is more like a legacy software :)